# Add custom field in shipping and billing section onepage at checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I have to add one custom field in shipping and billing area call something like"ConfirmZip Code"  i have searched lot of tutorialsbut now worked for me ia using magento 1.9.1